# Remote browsing files on Shiny using SSH

Tags: r, ssh, shiny

I want a shiny app to plot data that is stored on a remote server.

The server is configured so that I can connect via SSH using public/private keys.

I can use a `textInput` to get the user's login and another `textInput` to get the path of the data on the remote server and fetch the data via sFTP.

This works well but is not very user friendly.

I would like to use a file browser like `fileInput`, but this only shows local files.

Is it possible to configure it to browse the remote server?

**Edit:**

Additional requirement, the path has to be a directory path, not a file path.

Comment: If you have control over the server there are packages like [`sshfs`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh) which make it possible to do the filesystem-like browsing you're looking for, but you'll need to do some system administration to get it to be dynamic.

Comment: Not possible... I don't have root access. I'll stick to copy/paste of the path

Comment: @Ben were you able to solve this? I'm trying to do something similar. As the user enters credentials to sign in using Shiny UI. However, when a command is executed to run on the remote server from the shiny UI it fails as bash env. that shiny UI submitting the commands is different and does not have all the modules to work. Not sure, how to overcome this.

Comment: However, a similar approach on the Python flask worked.